# Move the item to the beginning

Tags: jquery, html

I have written a list of elements with the possibility of selecting html radio. I would like the div in which the field is selected to be moved to the very beginning of the list (above all elements of the list). Do you have any idea how I can do it?

My html code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="elements">
  <div class="element">
    <span>Option 1</span>
    <input type="radio" name="var" value="1">
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <span>Option 2</span>
    <input type="radio" name="var" value="2">
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <span>Option 3</span>
    <input type="radio" name="var" value="3">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: are you using any frameworks or just plain javascript?

Comment: you could probably get this effect with just css

Comment: I use only javascript and jquery

Comment: use jquery clone() on the element  you want to copy. Use prependTo() to prepend it to the form and delete the original element (which you cloned) with remove()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.elements .element input[type=radio]').change(function() {
  $(this).closest('.element').prependTo('.elements');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="elements">
  <div class="element">
    <span>Option 1</span>
    <input type="radio" name="var" value="1">
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <span>Option 2</span>
    <input type="radio" name="var" value="2">
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <span>Option 3</span>
    <input type="radio" name="var" value="3">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

So it can't quite be done with CSS alone. Until the CSS4 [:has selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) drops, we still have to use javascript to style a parent based on its child's status.

But we *can* use [flexbox to reorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) the elements (instead of removing them and re-adding them which causes issues saving the state of the element):

```js
const options = document.getElementById('options')

options.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(event.currentTarget.querySelectorAll('.element'))
  elements.forEach(element => element.classList.remove('selected'))
  event.target.closest('.element').classList.add('selected')
})
```

```css
#options {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.element {
    border: 1px solid #ace;
    order: 1;
}

.element.selected {
    border: 1px dotted #ace;
    order: 0;
}
```

```html
<form id="options">
  <div class="element">
    <label>Option 1
        <input type="radio" name="var" value="1">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <label>Option 2
      <input type="radio" name="var" value="2">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <label>Option 3
      <input type="radio" name="var" value="3">
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
        $('input[type=radio][name=var]').change(function () {
        var divClassElement = $("span:contains('Option " + this.value + "')").parent();
        divClassElement.prependTo($(".elements"));
    });
})
```

Answer (score -2):

Append the selected item then remove it from the list

Remove: https://api.jquery.com/remove/
Append: http://api.jquery.com/append/